# NetBeans Xdebug take in front on active breakpoint

Tags: netbeans, xdebug

I am using NetBeans 8.2 with PHP and Xdebug.

Everything working fine but just one issue I am facing, like not issue but needed feature.

**Scenario**

- I set all required breakpoints
- I go back to browser and start doing all operation

Now the problem is when any breakpoints triggers its stopped execution over there but I didn't get any idea about that because I am still on the browser window.

So how to get notified or get NetBeans window active on breakpoints get active?